# Geometry of fonts

Tags: winapi, fonts, gdi+, gdi, font-size

If I want to draw a text on a control, I can get "a bounding rectangle" first and place it at an appropriate place (using `GetTextExtentPoint32` function).

But I also need to know where some baselines are, e.g the two red lines in the picture.
(Their positions are calculated respect to the top of the bounding rectangle.)

I didn't figure a way to get these information. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `GetTextMetrics` will get you this. Select your font into the DC first, then call `GetTextMetrics`. The fields `tmAscent` and `tmDescent` of the `TEXTMETRIC` structure are probably the ones you need.